# Css, main part is always a curtain height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, height

At the site we are developing we have a main part (div main and mainholder) and this has always a maximum height of 770px. If the content in that part is higher then that it is cut of at the page, but we want the height to be automatically the same height as the content. So we do not want to give it a fixed height but it has to change automatically.

Comment: You can use the secret "curtain" unit: `height: 1ctn`. -shot-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `height: 100%;` to `min-height: 100%;` for class `.post`

Comment: Regarding the backward compatibility - the `min-height` property is supported only in IE8+, keep in mind that. Also IE8 has some bugs with `min-height/max-width/height` combined with `overflow: auto/scroll`.

Comment: If you don't want that minimum height, remove min-height from .post completely. If you then want the black background to still completely fill the screen, add `height:100%; margin-top:-70px; padding-top:70px; box-sizing:border-box;` to .major-holder

It's a somewhat sloppy hack, though.